# Wordpress Simple Fields nested foreach

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I really cant figure out how to insert another filed inside my foreach loop, i have the image variables but not sure how to incorporate it in this ?

```
<?php
 $repeatable_field_values = simple_fields_values("text_page");
 $file_id = simple_fields_values('image_post');
 $image_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src($file_id, "full");
 foreach ($repeatable_field_values as $values) { 

 echo " <li>
 <div class='small-12 large-6 columns text'>
 $values><div class='small-12 large-6 columns'><img src=$image_info></div>
 </li>";
 }
 ?>
```

This is the content filed and it works : 
`$repeatable_field_values = simple_fields_values("text_page");`

Bit the image filed im not sure how to insert it :

```
$file_id = simple_fields_values('image_post');
     $image_info = wp_get_attachment_image_src($file_id, "full");
```

This is how it looks like in wp admin :

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: i forgot to say the code above is not showing the image only text, i need another way to make this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution :**

```
 <?php $getfields = simple_fields_get_post_group_values(get_the_id(), "Field group name", true, 1);
$count = 0;
if($getfields["Field1"][0]!="") {
foreach($getfields["Field1"] as $options) { ?>

<?php $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($getfields["Field1"][$count], 'thumbnail'); ?>
<li>
    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns text"> 
<?php echo($getfields["Field2"][$count])?>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-6 columns">
    <img src="<?=$imgsrc[0]?>" />
</div>

</li>

<?php $count++; }} ?>
```

Field group name : Just type the name  of the field, not the slug

Field 1 and Field2 : im not sure if here goes the name or the slug but i have named the slug and the name the same because i was in a hurry didn't had time to test but i think the name goes here like in the field group name.